# How to construct multiple routes and rendered templates that are using the same function in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a web app using Flask, where multiple routes and templates are using the same function that requires heavy computation. So, the app ends up with repeating these heavy calculations multiple times. Below is the simplified code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, url_for, Markup, send_from_directory
from AnotherModule import perform_heavy_calculations, convert_dataframe

@application.route('/<string:keyword>', methods=['GET'])
def index(keyword):
    dataframe = perform_heavy_calculations (keyword)
    session['keyword'] = keyword
    return render_template ("index.html", dataframe = dataframe)


@application.route("/timeseries.json", methods=['GET'])
def timeseries (keyword):
     keyword = session.get ('keyword')
     dataframe = perform_heavy_calculations (keyword)
     timeseries =  convert_dataframe (dataframe)
     return render_template ("timeseries.html", timeseries = timeseries)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

As you can see, the function perform_heavy_calculations (keyword) is repeated twice - once in every route. This makes the app very slow. In this case two times slower then if this function were performed once and the results are used in two different routes with rendering different templates. 
I can't pass the results in session since the dataframe is too large. 
Also, I can't perform the function outside of routes, since the argument (keyword) will be passed only with get request submitted in '/' route.

What would be the best way to avoid performing the function twice, but perform it only once with the result being used in two different templates?

Thank you,

Anton

Comment: Well, in theory you could store the results in a session, just not the default Flask session. For example, see [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/). I do something similar and dump the result to a `'filesystem'` session but you could store pre-computed data in redis to make access fast.

Comment: It kind of depends on what data your storing, but if the data is not changing after calculating it, why not just write it to the hard drive or a database?

Comment: @Joost, thanks. The data is the pandas dataframe that is calculated based on different inputs (keywords) and is different in different point of time

Comment: @roganjosh, thanks! let me try it and get back to you

Comment: You could just write the df as e.g. a .csv or a pickle, the question remains how do you know the df has to be updated/recalculated. But with either storing the df in the session or on the harddrive, that problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I recommend you to add caching support for the `perform_heavy_calculations()` function. Check out [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: thanks! Let me try it and get back here with results

Comment: Thanks @Grey Li, I went with your suggestion, see the answer below. I can't upvote your answer since I don't have enough reputation yet!

Comment: You are welcome! If you think my answer is helpful, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I went with using cache vs session since it allowed to store the results for the different users and different keywords. Below is the simplified code that I used.

```
dataframe = cache.get(keyword)
    if dataframe is None:
        dataframe = perform_heavy_calculations (keyword)
    cache.set(keyword, dataframe, timeout=60 * 60)
```

This can be used across multiple views and functions.
Thanks all a ton for your help!

Anton